# Store Postgresql data on external drive

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgresql 14 on desktop and laptop using Windows 10. Would someone please show me how to store the data on an external SSD drive so that I can just move the drive to different computer and not having to restore? I am thinking about learning Ubuntu because people on the web say Postgresql run faster on Ubuntu. Thank you so much in advance for your instruction!

Comment: This is not going to work for 1) You cannot have Postgres from different architecture's and OSes run against the same data directory. 2) The locale, collations, etc will be different and will corrupt the data. 3) The chance's that you make the move with a clean data directory are slim to none.  You are going to have to dump/restore.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I am grateful for your reply! I meant so put the Windows Postgres 14 data on the external SSD drive so that I can use it on a Windows Postgres 14 on a desktop or a Windows Postgres 14 on a desktop with out restoring. Is it possible? Thank you again!

Comment: I would say it would not be a good thing to do. The chances of a unclean shutdown are high, at which point your data could become corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Adrian. You save me from wasting time