# Store Postgres data on an external SSD drive so I can use the drive on different computer

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres 14 on my Windows desktop and laptop. How can I put Postgres data on an external SSD drive so I can switch using Postgres between 2 computer without doing restoring. Thank you so much in advance for your instruction!

Comment: Google: Can you start two (or more) PostgreSQL instances against the same data directory?

Comment: Asking the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324520/store-postgresql-data-on-external-drive) twice is not going to get you a different answer.